# How to display an image to my panel in WXPYTHON

Tags: python, wxpython, wildcard

I want to display an image into my panel in wxPython and i don't know how to do that. Here is my code:

```
def onClick(self,Event):
        wildcard='PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg'
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", wildcard,wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        openFileDialog.ShowModal()
        url=openFileDialog.GetPath()
        img=mpimg.imread(url)
```

Basiclly it works just fine. I browse for my image, i get it's url into a variable(url) and then in another variable (img) im saving my image from my pc. My problem is the following: I want to add the "img" above the "browse" button and i don't know how to do this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use wx.StaticBitmap.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(2, 1, 10, 10)
        fgs.AddGrowableRow(0)

        self.staticbitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self)
        fgs.Add(self.staticbitmap, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        browse = wx.Button(self, label='Browse')
        browse.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBrowse)
        fgs.Add(browse, flag=wx.LEFT)

        self.SetSizer(fgs)

    def OnBrowse(self, event):
        wildcard = 'PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg'
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", wildcard,
                                       wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        openFileDialog.ShowModal()
        url = openFileDialog.GetPath()
        self.staticbitmap.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(url))
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What exactly does this variable contain?